# Oracle Linux new files written on share do not inherit correct group in production environment

Tags: linux, oracle, directory, permissions, nfs

We have an issue regarding groups and files not being found by our application that are written on a share.

Our company wants to have a certain paper form signed digitally, our solution to this question is to make our application running on `Oracle Forms`  mail these digital forms. We got it working in our test environment but not our production environment. We have our `Oracle Report writer` write the filled in form as an PDF to a directory on our application server, this is a nfs share hosted by our IT collegue's. Our database server then reads the mounted share and sends the PDF as an attachment per mail. This all happens from a database trigger which is copy/pasted over to production.

In our production environment we get the Report writer to write the PDF in the shared directory but then our database server generates an error log message saying the server can not find the file. I notice that the test environment writes down the PDF file as `user:group` and the production environment as `user:1000`, I have a feeling this is causing the database server to not find the file.

It is an Oracle Linux machine running Database 12.2 and Forms/Reports 12.2

Test:
`Report Writer` on `App server 1` writes `1.pdf` > `/dir/test/share`
`Database server 1` reads `1.pdf` from `/dir/test/share`

Production:
`Report Writer` on `App server 2` writes `2.pdf` > `/dir/prod/share`
`Database server 2` reads `2.pdf` from `/dir/prod/share` > cannot find `2.pdf`

[Group id changes to "1000"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svjPx.png)

[directory shared group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF3Jh.png)

Does anyone have an idea what this might be, this has to go live very soon but I am out of ideas.

Any help would be **greatly apprieciated!**

Best regards,

Roël

Comment: Does the database use a directory object to access the files? Make sure the directory object points to the correct file system directory, and that the oracle OS user has access to that directory and the files (looks like it does probably does have permission).

Comment: For anyone that might have a simular issue: Apperently for some reason Database server 2 was trying to read the file on App server 1. This was the issue.